# Unable to find package but package is installed (.NET / ASP.NET CORE)

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, devextreme

we're using DevExtreme for ASP.NET and .NET core for a project.

I pulled the project that my partner made, which worked on his system, and I can't build. The error stating that it's unable to find the package
[Error log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RZUfo.png)

I've installed the DevExtreme onto my PC and restarted both the computer and the IDE.

Here's proof they're installed 
[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yxdbU.png)

First time posting on stack overflow so I'm not sure if my post etiquette is up to par, sorry.
Need help figuring out this error

Answer (score 0):

Seems, it(DevExtreme.AspNet.Core) say "not available on this source"

The DevExtreme.AspNet.Core library is a part of DevExtreme. I guess Your account contains only the ASP.NET subscription, which does not include DevExtreme.

hope this helps: 
https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/T524333/devextreme-aspnet-core-is-not-available-in-nuget-repository

Answer (score 0):

The package `DevExtream.AspNet.Core` does not exist in [nuget.org](https://nuget.org). You can always go to that website and search for packages on that website. Both your screenshots show that visual studio was unable to find this package too.

Visual Studio by default uses the source of your nugets as nuget.org. You would see this in the top right corner of your "proof" screenshot. In this screenshot, you can also see the text "Not available from this source" below `DevExtream.AspNet.Core` at the left. This is a visual studio telling you it is not installed.

In your first screenshot, the last error says the package is not found. The first two errors seem to be related to the last (if you don't have a package installed, it can't find the namespaces).

It seems like your partner's system used a different source for these NuGet packages. In your partner's NuGet package manager check for the nuget source used. You can click the settings icon to the right of the source dropdown to configure it. Check [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/install-use-packages-visual-studio#package-sources) for more info.